# Web Hosting companies that support Ruby, Python, PHP, and ASP.NET

Tags: hosting, web-hosting

I was looking at godaddy.com and they support PHP, ASP.NET, and ColdFusion for their Windows plan and for their Linux plan, they support PHP, Ruby, Python, Perl, etc. Does anyone know if I can still run Ruby and Python on a Windows Plan or is this usually not done with Web Hosting Companies? I would really like the option to register one domain and have the ability to use Ruby, Python, PHP, or ASP.NET

Answer (score 1):

If it is shared plan, the answer is probably 'NO' but you can ask the specific hosting company directly. However, nothing prevents you to install, say Pytnon interpreter on a dedicated Windows box. The right choice in your case could be a windows [VPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) account with full administrative access, so that you are able to install whatever software you need.

Answer (score 0):

Check out

http://webhostingtalk.com

You'll get a better idea of who does what where right now.

Cheers,
-Mathew

Answer (score 0):

this website give good and cheap plans
http://services.seekdotnet.com/aff.php?aff=092